# Poisson distribution for calculation of number of calls

Tags: probability, poisson-distribution

A roadside assistance center receives 2 calls every half hour on average.
a) Find the probability for this center to get at least 3 calls in two hours.

b) If the center received 3 calls in the first hour, find the probability for the center to receive 5 calls in the next hour.

> This is clearly Poisson distribution.
> For a):
> 2 calls every half hour means 8 calls in two hours on average.
> Probability of at least 3 calls is
> $P(X \geq 3) = 1-P(X=0)-P(X=1)-P(X=2)$.

> $\mathbb{P}\{X=0\} = e^{-\lambda} \frac{\lambda^0}{0!} = e^{-8} \frac{8^0}{0!}$ and similarly for the others, so I get $P=0.9862$.

> How do I calculate the probability for the second case? I am a bit confused.

**Edit:** Since the two intervals are disjoint, the two probabilities will be independent, so we will calculate them and multiply. Is this so?

Thank you!

Comment: You are right about the independence. I'm not sure if this question is supposed to be like that but the way it is formulated, conditioning on the having 3 calls in the first hour doesn't matter at all. So you can just model the calls in the second hour using a Poisson variable with parameter 4. Do you see how to go from here?